# PHP simple text database with SQL syntax

Tags: php, sql, database, text, flat

I am looking for a simple text flat database that can work with the SQL-like instructions SELCT, INPUT, UPDATE, DELETE.
There is a database that fully satisfies me, but it is for Perl - http://metacpan.org/pod/Sprite
I need something like that, but PHP class.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does it need to have text as a backend, or do you just want something portable? In other words, have you considered SQLite?

Answer (score 6):

Use [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite). It has a PHP class too here:
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2107-PHP-SQLite-database-access-wrapper.html

Comment: SQLite is installed in PHP5 by default.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php

Comment: Not plain text, but at least it's saved in a file not behind a server.

Comment: SQLite is most certainly _not_ a flat file database.

Comment: +1.  I love that database.  I don't get to use it nearly enough.

Comment: SQLite is amazing! But this php hosting doesn't support it :(

Answer (score 2):

Apparently stalled or abandoned but quite what you are looking for:

**PHP Text File Database API - PHP Text DB: access Text Files with SQL**

- http://www.c-worker.ch/txtdbapi/index_eng.php, also at
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/flatfiledb/

**PHP Flatfile package - provides equivalents to many common SQL commands**

- http://lukeplant.me.uk/resources/flatfile/

Answer (score 1):

is this what you're looking for? [askSam](http://www.asksam.com/solutions/text%20database.asp)

Answer (score 1):

file = table
folder = database

http://nodb.at/

ASAP - as simple as possible

the idea is like this:

database = folder

table = subfolder

column = file in subfolder

record = a line in column-file ;)

so theoretically you could have a table inside a table or even work with filesystem links (linux ln -sv command)